# How can one create a custom "as_table()" method for forms?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a relatively complicated form that's used in multiple places on my website (in fact, it's a form from which many other form classes inherit). In the templates, the inherited part of this form is always formatted identically—but that formatting is somehwat involved; each field is rendered and positioned manually in the template.

This means that every template which displays this form has a lot of identical HTML markup that renders the form appropriately.

I would like to create a custom output that can be called, similar to the `as_table()` methods. I'm aware that one can override the `normal_row`, `error_row`, etc. attributes—but the formatting of this form goes beyond that (for example, three of the form's five fields should be printed side-by-side, with a combined title). All of the tutorials/answered-questions I've seen either refer to overriding the above-mentioned attributes, or give instructions on how to manually render forms.

Originally, I was thinking something like this:

```
Class StrangeForm(form.Forms):
....
    def as_table_custom():
        html_string = "\
           <tr><td>Title 1:</td><td>self.fields['field1']</td><tr>\
           <tr><td>Title 2:</td><td>self.fields['field2']</td><tr>\
           <tr><td>Titles 3, 4, 5:</td><td>self.fields['field3']\
           </td><td>self.fields['field4']</td><td>self.fields['field5']</td></tr>\
        "
    return html_string
```

But, after reading through the `_html_output()` and `as_table()` methods of [Django's forms.py file](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py), it doesn't look like it'll be that easy. If I write this from scratch, have to somehow account for errors, help text, etc. I think.

Is there an easy way to override something such that the form's HTML output can be defined like above? Or do I have to re-write things from scratch. If the latter, how can I account for all of the things I need to account for?

Comment: Why not just extract the template code into a separate file and `{% include %}` it where necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't take this approach. You're better off creating the form in an HTML template that you include in the various templates where you have a form you want to display that way.

So create a my_strange_form.html template where you assume a 'form' object is passed in the context with the right number of fields. In that template just create the HTML, using things like `{{ field.label_tag }}` and `{{ field }}`. You can loop through the fields with a `{% for field in form %}` and check the counter of your loop with `{{ forloop.counter }}`. I foresee a lot of `{% if forloop.counter... %}` statements to generate the combined row, and it will look ugly, but you'll only have to look at it once :-)

Then in your main templates `{% include 'my_strange_form.html' with form=form %}`.